# Как вывести все элементы массива (объекта) в dart/flutter?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk, flutter, dart

Обычно в других языках программирования (`php`,`js`) выводил так:

```
var a=["1","2","3"];
var len=a.length;

for(var i = 0; i<=len; i++){a[i];}
```

А здесь такая коллекция (`dart/flutter`):

```
[{"id":"0","data":"one"},{"id":"1","data":"two"},{"id":"3","data":"three"}]
```

Как с помощью цикла получить такой список:

```
"id":"0","data":"one"
"id":"1","data":"two"
"id":"3","data":"three"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот два варианта, как это можно сделать.

Первый - самый простой. Второй - точь-в-точь, как вы просили в вопросе.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final listOfMaps = [{"id":"0","data":"one"},{"id":"1","data":"two"},{"id":"3","data":"three"}];
  // Вот самый простой вариант:
  listOfMaps.forEach((map) => print(map));
  // Второй вариант (если нужны строки с кавычками и без фигурных скобок):
  listOfMaps.forEach((map) => print(JsonEncoder().convert(map).replaceAll(RegExp(r"{|}"), '')));
}
```

Быстро опробовать можете [тут](https://dart.dev/#try-dart), просто вставив код выше.